# Volley return 403 error

Tags: android, android-volley

[image][image]From two days i am trying to solve this issue but still i have no any result,why each and every time volley returning me 403 error. where i m wrong? i am using postman to check same webservice, it returns success result. But same thing when i am using in Android via volley or httpurlconnection getting 403 error.kindly help me to find my error.

This is my code which i have tried:

```
  StringRequest jsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constant.posturl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                      String result=response;
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                        int status = response.statusCode;

                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                        try {
                              headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                              headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                              String credentials = Constant.USERNAME + ":" + Constant.PASSWORD;
                              String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                              headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                              return headers;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                             return headers;
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("title", heading_edit_text.getText().toString());
                        params.put("content", body_edit_text.getText().toString());
                        params.put("Slug", heading_edit_text.getText().toString());
                        params.put("date", currentDate);
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(50000, 3, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: 403 Would be Forbidden. Are you able to copy your Postman request here (redact anything that should be private!). You can, in postman click the Code link and copy HTTP...

Comment: @Redman my username and password is right because i am using same username and password in postman also.Postman returns success result.

Comment: You should check if the base64 encoded token matches for your postman request and app request

Comment: yes it is matching,even some time  i also checked it by using same string in App which i am using in postman.

Comment: @Gavin Harris i edited my question with postman image...please check it and let me know where i am doing wrong in app.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also re-run the app after adding `VolleyLog.DEBUG = true;` in the `onCreate` method?

Comment: By the way, `Constant.PASSWORD` is a string constant in your app that can be decompiled and seen by anyone. Encoding it afterwards is pointless

Comment: Anyways, have you tried using JsonObjectRequest since you are sending and receiving JSON?

Comment: @Gavin Harris I added and checked internal library class hurl stack and Basic Network class also...still getting 403 error.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes i have tried.but i got same 403 error message.

Comment: I'm guessing the Base64 string is not the exact same. But you're not showing that, so it's hard to really help

Comment: @cricket_007  Base64 string is exact same as i am using in postman.I already checked it by writing same string in app.like this,headers.put("Authorization", "Basic "XXX");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135732/discussion-between-reema-singh-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 0):

Volley does provide a proper request for this which is called `JsonObjectRequest`.

```
 String webAddress = "url here";
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); // singletone here

 JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
 try {
     object.put("title", heading_edit_text.getText().toString());
     object.put("content", body_edit_text.getText().toString());
     object.put("Slug", heading_edit_text.getText().toString());
     object.put("date", currentDate);
 } catch (JSONException e) {
 }

 JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, webAddress,object, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

     @Override
     public void onResponse(JSONObject object) {
         Log.d("RESPONSE", object.toString());
     }

 }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
         Log.d("RESPONSE", "That didn't work!");
     }

 }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                // content type is not needed here
                header.put("Authorization", "value here");
                return header;
            }

  };
 queue.add(request);
```

Comment: @ReemaSingh why you said so?

Answer (score 0):

Change the "Content-Type" of your headers to "application/form-data"

ie,

```
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/form-data");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also face this issue in news api. But when I use Retrfit its work like a charm.